# JavaScript: Import video from youtube channels as API json to my website

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, frontend, youtube-data-api

If I have a YouTube channel URL, is there any way to use js  to get the associated data ( url, title, thumbnail, ...) from the YouTube API  ?

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api?rq=1) look like my question 
but i need access channel not once video.

Comment: I think you need [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#usage), this allows you to get information about the channel by channel id, username or by other.

On that page there is a demo where it shows how to get the result in different languages.

Comment: i tried this link last but no result